# Use of \hphantom{} at beginning of list \item

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, enumitem

It seems that `\hphantom{}` is ignored at the beginning of an `item`.  The MWE below yields:

[image]

How to get "First" and "Second" aligned?.

I know that you have to use `\hspace*{}` instead of `\hspace{}` at the beginning of a line, but it does not seem as if `\hphantom*{}` or `\phantom*{}` exist.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item {}\hphantom{x }First Item.
    \item x Second Item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: after `\item` TeX is in vertical mode.

Comment: `\leavevmode\hphantom{x }`

Comment: @egreg: I personally don't think that this is a duplicate of the linked question. Lists are quite different than `tabular`. I am not sure if had I seen that other question, if I would have realized it was the same problem. touhami's comment explains the problem and you provided the`\leavevmode\hphantom{x }` solution . So, as long as your comment does not get deleted, this is fine.